# Docker on Ubuntu 14.04.3 always getting "[8] System error: no such file or directory"

Tags: 14.04, docker

I had Docker working three weeks ago, but now I can't get anything except

```
no such file or directory
Error response from daemon: Cannot start container 7d3cb483971037da163fd8d220100728f51e055e7d0ae811a70bf2ef32564552: [8] System error: no such file or directory
```

I am going **batty** trying to get this to work.

docker version:

```
Client:
 Version:      1.8.2
 API version:  1.20
 Go version:   go1.4.2
 Git commit:   0a8c2e3
 Built:        Wed Oct  7 17:48:28 UTC 2015
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

Server:
 Version:      1.8.2
 API version:  1.20
 Go version:   go1.4.2
 Git commit:   0a8c2e3
 Built:        Wed Oct  7 17:48:28 UTC 2015
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
```

docker info:

```
Containers: 1
Images: 2
Storage Driver: aufs
 Root Dir: /var/lib/docker/aufs
 Backing Filesystem: extfs
 Dirs: 4
 Dirperm1 Supported: false
Execution Driver: native-0.2
Logging Driver: json-file
Kernel Version: 3.13.0-66-generic
Operating System: Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS
CPUs: 4
Total Memory: 7.74 GiB
Name: footscray
ID: IWMM:MCLX:3H5C:V4QA:JQA2:TVBM:F3PX:4VC4:45XZ:C6AT:TB75:QQNG
```

Output of `uname -a`:

```
Linux footscray 3.13.0-66-generic #108-Ubuntu SMP Wed Oct 7 15:20:27 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I am running on `localhost`.

Output of `docker run hello-world`:

```
Unable to find image 'hello-world:latest' locally
latest: Pulling from library/hello-world

535020c3e8ad: Pull complete 
af340544ed62: Pull complete 
Digest: sha256:a68868bfe696c00866942e8f5ca39e3e31b79c1e50feaee4ce5e28df2f051d5c
Status: Downloaded newer image for hello-world:latest
no such file or directory
Error response from daemon: Cannot start container b834de00b11decea01b36d1105352eca423bf708dda4b14016bab8fecd5bff41: [8] System error: no such file or directory
```

At first I'd used the `wget` method to install `docker`, but then I removed everything and used the method described in the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/installation/ubuntulinux/).

I've installed `app-armour` and made adjustments accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this issue - it's worth noting that my docker and AppArmor skills are rudimentary, so I'm not 100% sure of what's going on here.

When I first applied the AppArmor solution (aa-complain, per session) it worked. I then disabled the profile in general for consistency across reboots (as advised on the [Ubuntu wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AppArmor#Disable_one_profile)):

`sudo ln -s /etc/apparmor.d/docker /etc/apparmour.d/disable/docker`

When I deleted the entry in /etc/apparmour.d/disable, and just have the aa-complain set, docker starts to work again.

For reference, I set up a VM of Ubuntu 15.04 this AM and had exactly the same problem - this was how I found the solution.